# How to use @CachePut with @Cacheable annotation?

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am fetching a list of movies from below method with @Cacheable annotation. Since it does not have any parameter, I set key as #root.method.name.

```
@Cacheable(value="movieFindCache", key = "#root.method.name")
public List<Movie> getMovies(){
    ...
    return movies;
}
```

Now I want to add a new movie and same should be added to above cache.

```
@CachePut(value="movieFindCache", key="getMovies")
public void addNewMovie(){
    // create and add new movie to movies list
}
```

I tried this but it is giving me exception.

```
    org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
Property or field 'getMovies' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject' - maybe not public?
```

Can we use @CachePut annotation here or there is some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`key` is an Spring Expression language http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Try `''`

```
@CachePut(value="movieFindCache", key="'getMovies'")
```